# Sequential regressions leading to weirdly negatively biased coefficient

Tags: regression, linear-model, error

I am interested in the association between a variable X and a variable Z in the presence of a covariate Y. I have therefore estimated the following regression model: Z = a+bX+cY.

Reviewer #3 (a non-statistician) suggested that instead, I estimate the following regression Z = a'+c'Y, calculate its residuals (let's call them Eps) and then calculate the following regression: Eps = b'X.

Running the following simple toy example in R, I found that b' is always lower than b. Could anyone explain why?

```
N=1000
b=vector('double',N)
bprime=vector('double',N)
for (i in seq(1,N)){
  X=rnorm(100)
  Y=rnorm(100)
  Z=rnorm(100)+X+Y

  m1=lm(Z~1+X+Y)
  m2=lm(Z~1+Y)
  Eps=m2$residuals
  m3=lm(Eps~1+X)
  b[i]=coef(m1)['X']
  bprime[i]=coef(m3)['X']
}
hist(bprime-b)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that (unsurprisingly) the same effect is also observed if I use Eps~X rather than Eps~1+X.

Comment: `Eps~X` and `Eps~1+X` conveys the same thing as far as I know (both fits an intercept).